# Need of search bar in Stack Exchange API Documentation Pages

Tags: feature-request, support, search, api

The is a need of search bar in Stack Exchange API Documentation Pages. Eg. the place marked in the snapshot [image]

Comment: What would it find? What would you search for?

Comment: There was a parameter `site_type` to be given in one of the functions. I don't remember that function & am searching for it. Also, when Google was started, investors rejected it saying there is no market in web search.

Comment: Agree, like we can search the Help Center on any site.

Comment: https://developers.google.com is another example. Documentation pages have a search bar.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround (or a solution, since it's tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support)), use Google Search (or another search engine) and limit your search to the API documentation with the option `site:api.stackexchange.com/docs`. For example, [`site:api.stackexchange.com/docs "site_type"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aapi.stackexchange.com%2Fdocs+%22site_type%22) gives the following results:

[image]